# Why do I not get alerts when questions get closed or deleted?

Tags: support, feature-request

When people comment on or answer a question I post, I get notified via my "inbox". When people up/down vote my question, I get notified via my "achievements" box.

Shouldn't I also get notified if a question gets put on hold or closed or deleted?

For example, I only learnt what happened to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96240/what-is-this-vba-event-procedure-all-about) by actively searching a list of deleted questions.

Comment: There's been quite a few posts on Meta Stack Exchange about this. See e.g. [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94400/158667)